# jquery scrollbox scrolling stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

Hi i'm having problem with the scrollbox plugin [demo here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?RxWfQMJV).

It seems to scroll through the first logo fine then once it reaches the second logo it tries to scroll but stays stuck on the second logo.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/488Vr/

```
$('#erclients').scrollbox({
direction: 'h',
distance: 150
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is simply the result of a typo. Look really closely at the first list item you have:

```
<li class="erclientlogos"><a href="http://trelisecooperonline.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://kud4105web.e-retailer.co.nz/user/files/er_tc_logo.png"</a>
        </li>
```

You're missing a `>` to close out your image before the `</a>`. Add that and you should be good.

Comment: No problem. If this was the solution, please mark it as the answer. =)